# How to tell which format a controller has resolved to render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, respond-to

In a rails controller action with the following code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json{ render :json=>  {:status => 200, :response=>@some_resource} }
  format.html { redirect_to(some_resource_path)}
end
```

How can I log the format the controller will resolve i.e. 'HTML' or 'json'? `format` is of type [Collector](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d42d97d2e3f0bdef2163cc14daa181903e0b198d/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/collector.rb). Is there a way of getting a string denoting the format?

Comment: try params[:format]
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671111/methods-for-limiting-the-rails-render-format-to-html

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The method to access the format is:

```
controller.request.format
```

Comment: Thanks Anil. So from the controller it is just request.format.

Comment: Better to use request.format, because controller.request.format throws undefined local variable or method `controller'

Answer (score 20):

in your controller you can do:

```rb
request.format
request.format.html?
request.format.js?
request.format.json?
# etc.
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation on the available types or how they are built. Do you know where this is defined?

Comment: Using the `byebug` gem in my controller, I was able to type `formats` in the debug session and I got this output: `[:js, :html, :text, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :vtt, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :mp3, :ogg, :m4a, :webm, :mp4, :otf, :ttf, :woff, :woff2, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip]` See this documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html