# Why am I getting ActionView::MissingTemplate errors from production when the template exists and works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a pages controller in my Heroku-hosted Rails 3.2.8 app with several routes such as:

```
match 'contact' => 'pages#privacy_policy', :as => :privacy_policy
```

I have a corresponding `/app/views/pages/privacy_policy.html.erb`. I didn't explicitly write out action definitions in the controllers because these pages are just plain HTML.

Everything works, I've never produced an error, but my error-notifier sends me errors from production regularly such as:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template pages/privacy_policy,
application/privacy_policy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>["Accept: */*"],
:handlers=> [:erb, :builder]}. Searched in: * "/app/app/views"
```

Again, I have never been able to reproduce this error, but I get the notifications and worry that my customers are getting 500 pages. Any idea how I can reproduce this error, or better yet, solve it?

Comment: Is "/app/app/views" is right path? Maybe,there are some mistakes in relative urls in your application.

Comment: It isn't right. I don't know why it would be looking there. I'm guessing that happens only under some unknown set of circumstances.

Comment: Hi Nathan, did you fix this problem? I am getting exactly same error.
But because it happens rarely(about every 3 or 4 days), I can't debug.
When I debug it working well on my local so I can't find reason

Answer (score 0):

It could be something requesting a text or xml format or some other [mime type](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to#14-Rails-defined-Mime-Types). I occasionally get messages like that from my notifier too, but they happen so sporadically that I haven't addressed it yet.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671111/methods-for-limiting-the-rails-render-format-to-html) seems to be a thread addressing that particular problem.