# How can I set my Rails controllers to, by default, only accept HTML requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Most of my controllers only have meaningful responses in HTML. Consider the following scenario:

I make a simple controller

```
class FrontController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

and provide an `app/views/front/index.html.erb`. If I hit that action with `Accept: text/html`, it renders that template, as expected.

If I hit that action with `Accept: application/xml`, I want to get a `406 Not Acceptable`. Instead, Rails raises an `ActionView::MissingTemplate` exception, and shows a `500` error:

> Missing template front/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xml], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.

---

There are two ways I've been able to get a `406 Not Acceptable` out of the controller. First, I can use a `respond_to` block:

```
class FrontController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |f|
      f.html
    end
  end
end
```

Second, I can use `respond_with`, though it looks pretty weird in a controller that doesn't represent a resource:

```
class FrontController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def index
    respond_with # No arguments, because there's nothing to put here.
  end
end
```

Either of those will respond to an XML request with a `406`. However, both require adding code to every controller action.

---

Here's what I'd like to be able to do:

- Ideally, I'd like an action that renders implicitly (with no `render` call or explicit formats declared) to return `406` if no template is found. That seems like a sensible default for Rails in general, and I'm surprised it doesn't do that already.
- Failing that, I'd at least like to be able to declare `:html` as the only acceptable format for all my controllers by default (and let any explicit format declarations in individual controllers and actions override that).

Ideas?

*(Rails 4.0.1, Ruby 2.0.0)*

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it contains a lot of related information & might be helpful for others passing by your question: [Methods for limiting the Rails render format to html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671111/methods-for-limiting-the-rails-render-format-to-html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643738/rails-3-respond-to-default-format I think this one is what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use responds_to, you can do this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :allow_only_html_requests

  ...

  def allow_only_html_requests
    if params[:format] && params[:format] != 'html'
      render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/404.html"
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: That's *too* restrictive. I just want `:html`-only to be the default if no other formats are explicitly provided.

Comment: (Also, the response should set the status to `:not_acceptable`, and rendering an HTML response is probably not the best way to respond to a request that specifically asked for something other than HTML.) :)